# Why cant I check if something is not empty

Tags: php, file, if-statement, upload

I'm trying to validate if a image is uploaded or not.
But I can't figure this out since 2 hours...:

Input: ""

My Code:

```
$_SESSION["errorMessage"] = empty($image);
```

Output: 1 (true)

Then I want to check if it isnt empty:

```
$_SESSION["errorMessage"] = !empty($image); // Or empty($image) == false
```

But then The Output is nothing?!?!

Even If I try the first one out it, when it should be true, gives out: ""

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The first one solves your problem its returns true or false depending on $image

Comment: No it doesnt. It doesnt work. If it should be true then it gives out ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you echo a false value, it won't echo anything.  You have to tell php what to show, e.g. `echo $_SESSION["errorMessage"] ? 'true' : 'false';`  In your case you may want to cast it to an int: `$_SESSION["errorMessage"] = (int)empty($image);` You could also use var_dump to verify, i.e. `var_dump( $_SESSION["errorMessage"] );`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE value:

```
function isset_file($file) {
    return (isset($file) && $file['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE);
}

if(isset_file($_FILES['input_name'])) {
    // It's not empty
}
```

Since sending $_FILES['input_name'] may throw a Notice

```
function isset_file($name) {
    return (isset($_FILES[$name]) && $_FILES[$name]['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE);
}

if(isset_file('input_name')) {
    // It's not empty
}
```

Another example to try:

```
if ($_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name']!='') {
    // do this, upload file
} // if no file selected to upload, file isn't uploaded.
```